# Implement youtube data app without oauth

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to implement the youtube data api without asking the user for their google account. Is it possible? My requirement is that user should be able to search for youtube videos even if they have not selected the google account.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your own google account instead of theirs and thus have a google account and proceed as normal.

I guess the other option is to write your own scraper or find an existing library that can do this without a google account being passed in.

Edit: as I said in the comments, it appears it doesn't make sense to use the data API without the user logging in since the API is meant to access private user data that requires authentication.

Comment: how can i use my own account? Do i need to save it locally in shared preferences?

Comment: What language are you using the data API from?

Comment: I'm using it in android(JAVA).

Comment: I just did some reading on the YouTube data API and if you're using the one I was reading about it sounds like the whole point of the API is to access private user data, in which case this would be impossible, and rightly so, without the user logging in. I might have been reading about the wrong API though?

Comment: can you provide me the link of the api you were reading so i can confirm?

Comment: yes i am using the same one but for android https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android